# how receivedata from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax method and I need to send this data to my controller. However, I don't know how to receive this data to my controller.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/art/Ajouter",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {
                       "Num": Numm,
                       "cl" : cl,
                       "global" : global
                    },
            success: function (responseText) {
                        debugger;
                        if (responseText == "True") {
                            alert("Succes");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
        });
```

and this how i  create the variable global

```
var global = [];
            function GetValues() {
                debugger;
                var myList = $("#multiSelect");
                var yy = $("#article").val();

                var Selectedelement = $("#quantiCommande").val();

                myList.append('<option value=' + Selectedelement + '>' + Selectedelement + " " + yy + '</option>');
                global.push({ "id": yy, "qte": Selectedelement });

            }
```

i add a class :

```
public class products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string qte { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the code  of my controller

```
public Boolean Ajoutercommande(string Num, int cl, string global)
        {

            CRUDEntities db = new CRUDEntities();
            Commande c = new Commande();
            c.NumCommande = Num;

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            products[] persons = js.Deserialize<products[]>(global);
            c.Quantité = cl;
            db.Commande.Add(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

and that's the form of table global in javascript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs3wx.png)

Comment: create a DTO in your MVC/API which maps to your parameters. Also, you need to set the content-type of your post to text/json.

Comment: show your controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove data type: json

It will cause the call to fail if the controller does not return json data

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/art/Ajouter",
        type: "POST",
        data : {
                   "Num": Numm,
                   "cl" : cl,
                   "global" : global
                },
        success: function (responseText) {
                    debugger;
                    if (responseText == "True") {
                        alert("Succes");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }
    });
```

Your controller would need to accept the passed data:

```
public Boolean Ajoutercommande(string Num, int cl, products[] global)
```

Comment: that does mean controller can't accept data type: json  steve?

Comment: No. If you omit the data type then json can be passed to the controller and the controller can return plain text content which is what it looks like your Ajax call is expecting to be returns. If you specify data type: json then Ajax expects both the post data and return type to be json.

Comment: i have a problem that global always null      and i add  the code of how i add in this table

Comment: Can you add the code for.your controller, and the definition for the global parameter

Comment: I have put what I think you need to change your action to be. You are passing an array of persons in the json data, so that is what the controller should receive.

Comment: steve the code fonctionne very well but no return success or error